# How is data augmentation done in each epoch?

Tags: python, pytorch, data-augmentation

I'm new to PyTorch and want to apply data augmentation to the datasets on each epoch. I

```
train_transform = Compose([
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(p=0.5),
    transforms.RandomCrop(32, padding=4),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1])
])

test_transform = Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1])
])

cifar10_train = CIFAR10(root = "/data", train=True, download = True, transform=train_transform)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(cifar10_train, batch_size=128, shuffle=True)

cifar10_test = CIFAR10(root = "/data", train=False, download = True, transform=test_transform)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(cifar10_test, batch_size=128, shuffle=True)
```

I got the code from an online tutorial. So from what I understand train_transform and test_transform is the augmentation code while cifar10_train and cifar10_test are where data is loaded and augmentation is done at the same time. Does this mean data augmentation is only done once before training? What if I want to do data augmentation for each epoch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some misunderstandings in your code. The `cifar10_train` and `cifar10_test` actually load the dataset into python (this data is not augmented and is the raw data), then the data goes through the transforms. In most cases, the training set is where the data augmentation is done, and the testing set is not augmented because it is supposed to replicate real-world data. The transforms (`train_transform` and `test_transforms`) are what decide how the data is augmented, normalized, and converted into PyTorch Tensors, you can think of it as a set of guidelines/rules for the dataset to follow. As mentioned before, the training set only gets augmented, which is why the train_transform has `RandomHorizontalFlip` and `RandomCrop` (which does augmentation), and why `test_transforms` does not have `RandomHorizontalFlip` and `RandomCrop`. The loaders (`train_loader` and `test_loader`) is what splits the data into batches (groups of data), and applies the transforms to the cifar10 dataset.

Comment: Thank you for helping, it helps me understood some. But what I still don't understand is that. During training for each epoch, the training data will always have different shapeof image because of transformation, right? So, from what I see in the following training code
```
for i in range(EPOCHS):
    start_time = time.time()
    ep = 0
    model.train()
    for X_b, y_b in train_loader:
        optim.zero_grad()
        X_b = X_b.to(device)
        y_b = y_b.to(device)
```
I don't see them applying transformation for each epoch.

Comment: The training data will always have the same shape of images, a neural network can only take in a constant amount of data, nothing smaller, or bigger. The transformation first does RandomHorizontalFlip and then resizes it to the set height and width of the image. I think your other question was already answered, but to answer it again the test data is only transformed one, and the training data is only transformed once. This occurs in the `CIFAR10` by setting transfomrs=transforms.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a rough flow of operations:

1. Read 128 examples from the filesystem.
2. *Batch* them (ie make a batch of examples) and apply the transformations on the batch.
3. Pass the batch to the network.

Hence, the transformations are applied to each batch before feeding it to the model, irrespective of the epoch.

Comment: Wait so, the dataset will only transform once? I thought if I run 10 epoch, for each epoch I will get a different version of datasets.

Comment: yes that is correct. These steps will be executed for each batch in each epoch :)